# Flash TextField vs Starling TextFiled

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, starling-framework

I have just started with Starling, and in the tutorial videos I always see that for displaying text they use a Starling TextField and Bitmap Fonts. My question is, what is the advantage/disadvantage of using a Starling TextField instead of a Flash TextField? I have to mention, I have sometimes lots of text to display.

regards

Comment: You have all of the answers here: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3371 (or directly here: http://www.bytearray.org/wp-content/projects/starling/introducing-starling-latest.zip)

Answer (score 0):

When working with starling you can't use Flash TextField as its not Starling DisplayObject. You can only use Starling TextField.

Also note that Starling does not have TextInput, you need to use one of it's extensions. I suggest you to use [com.gazman.ui.text.TextInput](http://gazman-sdk.com/docs/?com/gazman/ui/text/TextInput.html) from [Gazman SDK](http://gazman-sdk.com).